# .NET with Oracle (ODP.Net) - no data

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

We have 4 developers in my group and 2 of us can query Oracle data no problem from our .NET 3.5 asp.net webapp. But the other 2 get no results back, in the same exact query. In their case, if they replace the param with a hardcoded value, they get results back. For example:

select * from sometable where userid = :userid

(this works for 2 of us, but not the other 2)

select * from sometable where userid = '12345'

(this works for everyone)

We are all executing the same exact code, same exact query. Any idea why the parameterized query returns nothing for some of us?

Comment: Please post all your relevant code, including how you're connecting, assigning parameters, etc. Also, there's a `Code Sample` button in the text editor, which lets you format your code to be read more easily.

Comment: try with uppercase query. `SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE USERID = :USERID`

Comment: which oracle version is your app using? you may want to check odp.net settings. they are kept in registry prior to 11 but can be set in machine/app configs in 11 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guarantee you that it has nothing to do with code. On two machines where it doesn't work you either have wrong data access components. Or, .NET sucks in references to completely wrong objects, which don't break the compilation time but they don't support bind variables.  If you can, check which libraries are loaded into your domain object, it would be clear that you're loading completely wrong libraries.

Comment: We've checked all that. DLLs match, same references, same code.

Comment: Have you checked what DLL is actually loaded into domain? Have you checked if machines have exactly same client, point exactly to same SID? Machine bitness same? Your problem is there, somewhere.

Comment: How do I check which DLL is loaded into domain? What "domain" do you mean? Application pool or something?

Comment: var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();  ??

Comment: Yes, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies` should do it

Comment: We did that and confirmed that all machines are using the same ODP .net dll.

Comment: Well... Now. Reading your original post again. Did you make sure that in your "same query" (`select * from sometable where userid = :userid`), when it sets parameter for `:userid`, the value of that parameter is actually same value as if you execute fixed value? This would be the first step really. May be there is no row corresponding to the value that gets set into parameter. Re-check please. Verify again that the value and data type of the value are same on both machines. Normally, such mystery means something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

With-out seeing the code, I think it could be a parameter type issue. Oracle is a PIA with parameters. I had issues with DateTime vs TimeStamp before.
[Oracle date parameter query not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539489/oracle-date-parameter-query-not-working/14551553#14551553)

Are you using specific Oracle types?

Are you passing in the same value types every time? or is one and int and another a double?

```
public IDbDataParameter CreateParameter(IDbCommand cmd, string name, DbType type) {
    OracleParameter p = (OracleParameter)cmd.CreateParameter();
    p.ParameterName = name;
    p.OracleDbType = DBTypeToOracle(type);
    if (p.OracleDbType == OracleDbType.TimeStampLTZ) {
        p.Precision = 3;

    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Oracle converts your .NET types to Oracle versions, and sometimes it does a crappy job of it.

Comment: I think the main point is being missed. This has nothing to do with code. The same exact code works fine on 2 win7 machines, and on 2 others it doesn't work. Same code - on the 2 it doesn't work, it seems to not like the paramaterized queries. When we hardcode values on those 2 it works fine.

Comment: Is it the exact same parameter values on all machines? How about some code? Try make a Unit test with the same parameter value and run it on all machines.

Comment: FYI; In my case it was the exact same parameter value but it still failed, because Oracle converts your value to an Oracle version prior to insert (may lose precision) and then when retrieved later it's different. like .9999999999 vs 1 ; not say this is it, but could be...